# fastest way to minimize n as per given condition in python

Tags: python, optimization, bitwise-operators

how can i make the following code faster? the input is a binary string and i am converting it to a number. possibly i need to use the binary string instead of the number? the algorithm may only divide by 2 or subtract 1 from the input.  I tried the code below and it is not fast enough.

I tried the below:

```
def steps_to_zero(n) : 

    n=int(n,2)
    count = 0
    while n > 0:
        if n % 2 == 0:            
            n = n // 2
        else:  
            n = n - 1

        count += 1
    return (count)
```

It must be twice as fast as this:

```
def steps_to_zero_v1(x):
    x_int = int(x,2)
    steps = 0
    while x_int != 0:
        if x_int % 2 == 0:
            x_int = x_int // 2 
        else:
            x_int = x_int - 1
        steps += 1
    return steps
```

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What is "fast enough"? What else have you tried?

Comment: How fast should it be? What's the code's purpose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proposed code is doing exactly the same as the given code.
The main thing you want to look into to speed it up is getting rid of the expensive `if n % 2 == 0` test.

The solution is that you can reason about this problem on the bit-level without having to do any brute-force calculations.

For the trivial case `n=0` we get `count=0`. For the next simpler case `n=1` we only have to subtract 1 once, leading to `count=1`.

In all other cases, we're dealing with some longer binary number. If the last digit of that number is a `0`, we can divide by 2 to make our binary number a digit shorter:

```
...x0 / 2 = ...x  # 1 step for 1 digit shorter
```

Otherwise we have to subtract 1 first before we can divide by two.

```
...x1 - 1 = ...x0
...x0 / 2 = ...x   # 2 steps for 1 digit shorter
```

In other words: for the left-most 1 we need 1 operation, for all digits we need 1 if it's 0, and 2 if it's a 1.

This means that you can calculate this simply by counting the number of 1's in your string:

```
def steps_to_zero(n):
    n = n.lstrip('0')            # remove leading zeroes if they occur
    divisions = len(n) - 1       # don't have to divide for the left-most 1
    subtractions = n.count('1')  # each 1 needs a subtraction to become a 0
    return divisions + subtractions
```

Timing comparison between `% 2` and `.count('1')` averaged over 0-10,000:

```
# % 2
$ python3 -m timeit -s "x=list(range(10000))" "[y%2 for y in x]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 277 usec per loop

# .count('1')
$ python3 -m timeit -s "x=[bin(i) for i in range(10000)]" "[y.count('1') for y in x]"
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 msec per loop
```

Although `.count('1')` is ~5x slower than `%2` per execution, the `.count('1')` only has to be performed once, while `%2` has to be performed log2(n) times. This makes the `.count('1')` approach faster when `n > 2**5 (=32)`.

Comment: Yes, this code is faster. In fact it runs in constant time `O(1)` compared to the code from the OP which must be more like `O(n)` where n=len(n).

Comment: @quamrana it's still O(n) for the `n.count('1')` operation, but that operation is much faster than the `n%2` operation in OP's code

Comment: Yes, ok, you're right. That's the illusion that software sometimes has - making long operations look like they are done at once.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of converting the string to a number and performing expensive division and modulo operations, simply process it bit by bit. For each `1` bit except the leftmost one you'll need two steps (subtraction and division), and for each `0` bit you'll need one step (division):

```
def steps_to_zero(n):
    count = 0
    for x in n.lstrip('0'):
        if x == '1':
            count += 2
        else:
            count += 1
    return count - 1
```

Or, if you prefer one-liners:

```
def steps_to_zero(n):
    return sum((x == '1') + 1 for x in n.lstrip('0')) - 1
```